# multi-column index for string match + string similarity with pg_trgm?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, trigram

Given this table:

```
foos
integer id
string name
string type
```

And a query like this:

```
select * from foos where name ilike '%bar%'
```

I can make a [pg_trgm index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgtrgm.html) like this to make lookups faster:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foos USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops)
```

(right?)

my question: what about a query like this:

```
select * from foos where name ilike '%bar%' AND type = 'baz'
```

Can I possibly make an index that will help the lookup of both columns?

(I know that trigram isn't strictly fulltext but I'm tagging this question as such anyway)

Comment: Could you figure it out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible. But my question didn't get much attention. If you vote it up maybe it will get more :)

Comment: I could get my query optimized by using two indices. In your case it would be an index on name and another one on type. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html

Comment: @Macario cool, good to know. yep, we do have both indexes in place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a multicolumn index combining different types.

First, add the two extensions required in your case:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

[pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html) allows you to use trigram indexes and [btree_gist](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/btree-gist.html) allows you to **combine `gist` and `b-tree` indexes**, which is what you want!

For a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE type = 'baz' AND name ilike '%bar%';
```

You can now create an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo USING gist (type, name gist_trgm_ops);
```

As usual, the order of columns has to be the same between the query and the index.

Comment: n.b. there is also btree_gin: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/btree-gin.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foos(name, type)
```

However, you might want:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foos(lower(name), type)
```

I don't see why a full text index is needed for your queries.

Comment: a trigram or other strategy is necessary in order to partial matches inside of words, such as searching for "over" and matching "stackoverflow"

Comment: @JohnBachir . . . The OP is not using full text search functions in the question.  Are full text indexes going to be any better than a regular index *for the queries in the question*?

Comment: it's not fulltext, it's pg_trgm -- i've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @JohnBachir . . . And for the queries in the question, a b-tree index should work just as well.